# Why does CPanel show I/O faults when the site has low utilization?

Tags: cpanel, statistics, resources

I'm on a shared host and according to stats I'm not close to the limits, yet the resource usage stats show I/O faults:

[image]

Why are those fault lines there when the usage is well below the red limit?